# Wordpress and Magento: let Wordpress manage user registration and logins?

Tags: login, user-registration, customization, shared-user-tables

I need to integrate Magento and Wordpress for a corporate website.

There will be other functionalities in the website that will require a login (ie forum, helpdesk and maybe others...) which I would like to develop with Wordpress since I'm totally ignorant at the moment on Magento and looks a very complicated system for theming and extending.

The problem is user registration and logins: which system should handle those? Wordpress or Magento? What would be the best route to follow?

Thank you so much for any help or advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin Mage Enabler http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mage-enabler/ which makes Magento session available to WordPress, it's probably a good place to start. The author has written a couple of good posts on his blog detailing integrating the two.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has the wp_login.php page which contains lots of filters & hooks. I know this answer contains no code and such, but as you'd also need to hook into registration, password lost, etc. I'd say: just go and take a look :)

Comment: Thanks Kaiser, I was hoping there was someone already went through this and had a plugin or extension for it, but so far nothing. I don't think I have the ability to write one at the moment. Thanks anyway for pointing out where to start looking at.

Comment: I'd search a) the Repo b) WPSE c) Google for "double opt in". There might be something. I thought you want to write something yourself. Please mark the A as solution.